# Is there any problem to use measure as text labels instead of numeric value?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Usually we use measure to summarize numeric values. The measure shows numeric value.

Is there any problem to use measure to create text value. For example a measure called 'SalesClass' that classifies the sales as high/medium/low using a IF block. Can this be used on bar chart visual as axis.

I ask because I am have read that measure can only be used to summarize and not to group/filter.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to create measure of type STRING, but not to use measure as axis in visuals.

For instance, when using the FORMAT() function the returned value is of type STRING.

A possible way to create a measure that aggregate multiple string is through the usage of CONCATENATEX()

text measures cannot be aggregated by summing or averaging but can be aggregated by counting.

To have a representation of different values on an axis to be used to map a measure it's necessary to add a table in the model with a  column to be put on the axis (or a row, in case of a matrix) and then to implement DAX code to compute the value to be used when a filter exists on this table.